# how to know if the file is txt in linux

Tags: linux

I have a code where I need to delete all the `.txt` files in the main directory.

I have done a loop and in the loop there is if command:

```
if [ -f $file] 
then 
fi
```

now I need another if command where I check if the file is `.txt` or not.

Comment: Text is in the eye of the beholder

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407184/how-to-check-the-extension-of-a-filename-in-a-bash-script

Comment: when we make a new file

Comment: like touch j , j is a text file or it is only a text file if we do it like this: touch j.txt

Comment: because when I tried to see if it see a txt file it wasn't

Comment: The command `touch` is used to update the timestamps in an specific Inode. If the Inode does not exist yet, it will be created. Just because you updated the access time of a filesystem object does not mean, that you created any specific kind of file at all. You only created implicitly a generic object in the filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this, where the script determines the file type?

```
filename=testfile
fileType=$(file $filename | cut -d" " -f2)
  if [[ $fileType = "ASCII" ]]
    then
      echo "$filname is a test file"
    else
      echo "$filename is a $fileType file, not a text file"
  fi
```